# Java Swing; JFrame Popup

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a JMenuItem callback that calls a new instance of a derived class of JFrame.

Whenever the JMenuItem callback is called, the original popup is not brought back to the front of my main application.  Instead, it creates a new instance and a new window popup (so there are two or more of the same derived class).

How do I make it so there is at most one derived class instance at all time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there really should never be more than one instance of your derived class, you can make it a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), e.g.

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
   private static MyFrame instance = null;
   private MyFrame() {
      // Private to prevent instantiation.
   }

   public static MyFrame getInstance() {
      if(instance == null) {
         instance = new MyFrame();
      }
      return instance;
   }
}
```

You simply call `MyFrame.getInstance()` when you need to get an instance rather than using new, and will get the same one every time (it will be created the first time). e.g.

```
JFrame myFrame = MyFrame.getInstance();
// now call methods upon myFrame to make it pop up, etc.
```

If you'll be doing this from more than one place, then it would probably make sense to create a further static method in`MyFrame` and place the code in there. e.g.

```
public static void popUp() {
    JFrame myFrame = getInstance();
    // now call methods upon myFrame to make it pop up, etc.
}
```

Then you can simply call `MyFrame.popUp()`.

Comment: Worked like a charm! and I learned a new Design Pattern thanks to you :). mucho appreciated

Comment: I would just like to mention that your code isnt thread safe, and thats its very possible that in a multi-threaded environment that your Singleton pattern would fail.